# Animating shapes in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, animation

So I'm trying to have shapes animate across the canvas and then bounce back after hitting the edge, and I'm unclear why my other two shapes do not have velocity like my ball does. I'll post the code below.

```
<html>

<body>
  <section>
    <div>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="700" height="300"></canvas>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas,
        context,
    x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 400) + 1),          //Ball x coordinate
    y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 300) + 1),          //Ball y coordinate
    dx = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1),              //X velocity
    dy = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1),               //Y velocity
    width = 700,        //Width of the background
    height = 300;       //Height of the background


function drawCircle(x,y,r) {  //Draws the ball
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
  context.fill();
}


function drawRect(x,y,w,h) { //Draws the background
  context.beginPath();
  context.rect(x,y,w,h);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
}

function start() { //Runs when the window loads. Stores canvas and context      in variables. Runs "draw" on an interval of 10ms
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  return setInterval(draw, 10);
}

function drawSquare(){
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  if (canvas.getContext){
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(200,50);
    ctx.lineTo(250,50);
    ctx.lineTo(300, 100);
    ctx.lineTo(250,25);
    ctx.fill();



}

}



 function drawTri(){
 var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  if (canvas.getContext){
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(75,50);
    ctx.lineTo(100,75);
    ctx.lineTo(75,25);
    ctx.fill();
  }

}



function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height); //Clears the drawing space
  context.fillStyle = "black";            //Sets fillstyle to black (for the     background)
  drawRect(0,0, width, height);           //Draws the background
  context.fillStyle = "white";            //Sets fillstyle to white (for the     ball)
  drawCircle(x, y, 10); 
drawTri(); 
drawSquare(); //Calls function to draw the ball
  if (x + dx > width || x + dx < 0)       //If the ball would leave the     width (right or left) on the next redraw...
    dx = -dx;                             //reverse the ball's velocity
  if (y + dy > height || y + dy < 0)      //If the ball would leave the     height (top or bottom) on the next redraw...
    dy = -dy;                             //reverse the ball's velocity
  x += dx;                                //Increase ball x speed by     velocity
  y += dy;                                //Increase ball y speed by     velocity
}           
window.onload = start;                    //Run "start" function after the     window loads
</script>

  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to do the drawing with the variables. And the variables are the same (as in the 2 shapes will always be together) because if x is 150 for the circle, the rect will be behind it. So, you need more variables to keep track of it like this: circ1x,circ1y,circ2x,circ2y,rect1x,rect1y,rect2x,rect2y

Answer (score 0):

Your ball is being drawn using variable coordinates (x & y)

```
context.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
```

Your shapes are being drawn using hardcoded, constant values:

```
ctx.moveTo(200,50);
ctx.lineTo(250,50);
ctx.lineTo(300, 100);
ctx.lineTo(250,25);
```

&

```
ctx.moveTo(75,50);
ctx.lineTo(100,75);
ctx.lineTo(75,25);
```

To animate them, use variables to draw the other shapes, and update those variables. eg.

```
var x = 75,
    y = 50;
ctx.moveTo(x,y);
ctx.lineTo(x + 25, y + 25);
ctx.lineTo(x, y - 25);
```